# Solving tridiagonal system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

$${ \begin{cases}{2x_1+x_2=3} \\ {-x_1+2x_2+x_3=2} \\ {-x_2+2x_3+x_4=2} \\ {-x_3+2x_4+x_5=2} \\ {-x_4+2x_5=1}\end{cases} }$$

I am trying to use the method for solving tridaigonal system of equations explained [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UKoReqs_MzK3xdXyg8SrTqh75uI5ksK7/view?usp=sharing)

Consider $A$ as matrix of coefficients after doing some steps mentioned in the link I got: $$A={ \begin{bmatrix}{1} && {0} && {0} && {0} && {0} \\ {-\frac12} && {1} && {0} && {0} && {0} \\ {0} && {-\frac25} && {1} && {0} && {0} \\ {0} && {0} && {-\frac{5}{12}} && {1} && {0} \\ {0} && {0} && {0} && {-\frac{12}{29}} && {1}\end{bmatrix} }\times { \begin{bmatrix}{2} && {1} && {0} && {0} && {0} \\ {0} && {\frac52} && {1} && {0} && {0} \\ {0} && {0} && {\frac{12}5} && {1} && {0} \\ {0} && {0} && {0} && {\frac{29}{12}} && {1} \\ {0} && {0} && {0} && {0} && {\frac{70}{29}}\end{bmatrix} }$$
From Here I can't follow the method explained in the file it says :

$$x_n=\frac{g_n}{\beta_n}$$
$$x_j=\frac{(g_j-c_jx_{j+1})}{\beta_j},\quad j=n-1,\cdots,1$$

But I don't know how to find $x_1,\cdots,x_5$ from here. for example I got $x_1=\frac{g_1-x_2}{\beta_1}$ or $x_1=\frac{3-x_2}2$ and I don't know how  $x_n=\frac{g_n}{\beta_n}$ helps to find $x_1,...,x_5$.

Comment: Just go backwards: you know explicitly $x_n$; plug its value in the next equation, yielding $x_{n-1}$, etc.

Comment: Oh, I got it thank you.

Comment: @JeanMarie One more question, Isn.t this method the same as L-U decomposition ?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: It is strange. I am asked to solve this system first with tridiagonal method and second with L-U decomposition method !

Comment: The standard algorithm for solving a tridiagonal system is Thomas algorithm. Is it this one you have attempted to apply at first ?

Comment: @JeanMarie In my course they only taught us this method as tridiagonal method.

Comment: @philomath I guess you should let everyone has the permission to look at the Google Drive to understand some context.